# thymeleaf render partially on spring boot

Tags: spring, fragment, thymeleaf, spring-boot

I am using thymeleaf on spring boot for web application development.

Maybe i have to make many (html) pages.
But thymeleaf doesn't seem to support partial rendering.

I want something like 'yield' in ruby on rails.

Comment: Maybe a link to explain what you mean by "yield in ruby on rails" would help?

Comment: Thymeleaf has a lot of features. I think you have to explain what you mean by "partial rendering".

Comment: I resolved this problem. When I will go to my company, comment this again. Thank for you your attention

Comment: I refered this link http://t.co/t7qbi6PKvi

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is a question about views that share layouts using Thymeleaf. So the link that the OP shared in a comment is one way to handle it as a DIY solution. The [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect) is my preferred solution since it doesn't require me to write any code. Spring Boot makes it easy - just include "nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect" on your classpath. There's a [sample in the Spring Boot codebase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui).

Answer (score 0):

How about fragments in thymeleaf?

```
<body>
    <div th:include="fragments/footer :: footer">...</div>
</body>
```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html